# Get the top 5 most occurence from splitted text in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Im having a problem with this code. I want to get the most counted words in my splitted text in php can some one help me ? The codes shows that it gives the output of splitted text and i used count function of php to get the exact count for each specific word and the problem is i want to get the most counted word with at least top 5 because i will going to use this function to make a chart or analytic graph

[Picture of expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zsMk.jpg)

```html
<?php
$str = "one two three four five six set one two three four five six set one three four five six set one two three four five six set";
$a = preg_split("/[\s]/", $str);
foreach($a as $arr)
{
 echo $arr."<br>";
}


?>

<?php
$text = $str;

// $words = str_word_count($text, 1); // use this function if you only want ASCII
$words = utf8_str_word_count($text, 1); // use this function if you care about i18n

$frequency = array_count_values($words);

arsort($frequency);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($frequency);
echo '</pre>';


function utf8_str_word_count($string, $format = 0, $charlist = null)
{
    $result = array();

    if (preg_match_all('~[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\x{2019}' . preg_quote($charlist, '~') . ']+~u', $string, $result) > 0)
    {
        if (array_key_exists(0, $result) === true)
        {
            $result = $result[0];
        }
    }

    if ($format == 0)
    {
        $result = count($result);
    }

    return $result;
}


?>

<?php

$interesting = array($arr);
$string = "one two three four five six six six six six set one two three four five six set one three four five six set one two three four five six set one one one one";

// Explode into array
$array = explode(" ", $string);

// Group the values 
$count = array_count_values($array); 

// Sort the grouping by highest occurence to lowest
arsort($count);

// Get the keys of the most occurring
$keys = array_keys($count);

// compare key against the $interesting array for what you're interested in
$most_occurring = '';
foreach ($keys as $i) {
  if (in_array($i, $interesting, true)) {
      $most_occurring = $i;
      break;
  }
}

// Print output
echo "Most occurring $most_occurring, $count[$most_occurring] occurences.";

?>
```

Comment: as I understood, you give the script the dataset and it should output the max number of the repeat items, right?.

Comment: Explode, count (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php), then sort. Also don't use character classes unless needed, `[\s]` is the same as `\s`.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

1. `explode` turns the string into an array
2. `array_count_values` count the dupes
3. `arsort` sort the array
4. `array_slice` chunk off to get you top 5

Code:

```
$str = "one two three four five six set one two three four five six set one three four five six set one two three four five six set";
$arr = explode(' ', $str);
$vals = array_count_values($arr);
arsort($vals);
$top_5 = array_slice($vals, 0, 5); 
print_r($top_5);
```